# I want to add a success pop-up in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, toast

I'm trying to add a success pop-up in my login screen but I got 'response is not defined' error.

```js
axios.post('api', formValues)
    .then(response => {
        if (response === 200) {
            toast.success('login success');
        }
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch (error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: is you api call successful? did you checked network tab and its response?

Comment: yeah it is, the problem in here is with if statement

Comment: try this in your if check response.status

Comment: Please, fix your formatting to make the code snippet readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare it like that. Axios returns an object, which includes different things, for example the data or status code. You only want to compare the status code in your case. [check this link to see the construction of the response object](https://zetcode.com/javascript/axios/#:%7E:text=The%20Axios%20response%20object%20consists,message%20returned%20by%20the%20server). In your case, this should be response.status.

Taking into consideration of course that your request is succesful.